# Pygame -Images do not draw properly

Tags: python, pygame

I am making an ilumination system in pygame, so my code it's suppoused to draw little black rectangles over the screen and change their opacity when the flashlight image collide it. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import pygame

S_WIDTH= 800
S_HEIGHT= 600
FPS= 60

class cursor(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.Rect.__init__(self,0,0,1,1)
    def update(self):
        self.left,self.top=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

class flashlight():
    def __init__(self):
        self.IMG= pygame.image.load("B:/Proyectos pygame/Luz/linterna.png").convert_alpha()
        self.RECT= self.IMG.get_rect()
        self.RECT.top= 200
        self.RECT.left= 200

    def move(self,cursor):
        (self.RECT.top,self.RECT.left)= (cursor.top - 75,cursor.left - 65)

    def render(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.IMG,self.RECT)

class shadow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.number= 4
        self.size_x= 800/self.number
        self.size_y= 600/self.number
        self.ORIGINAL_IMG= pygame.image.load("B:/Proyectos pygame/Luz/shadow_lines.png").convert_alpha()
        self.IMG= pygame.transform.scale(self.ORIGINAL_IMG, (self.size_x,self.size_y))
        self.list= []
        self.RECT= self.IMG.get_rect()
        self.RECT.top= 0
        self.RECT.left= 0
        self.pixel_w= 0
        self.pixel_h= 0
        self.pos_x= -(self.size_x)
        self.pos_y= -(self.size_y)

        for x in range(self.number + 1):
            self.pos_x += self.size_x
            self.pos_y += self.size_y

            self.shadow= {"rect": self.RECT,
                          "img": self.IMG,
                          "pos_x": self.pos_x,
                          "pos_y": self.pos_y
                          }

            self.list.append(self.shadow)

    def render(self,surface):
        for shadow in self.list:
            surface.blit(shadow["img"], shadow["rect"])


def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    S_SURFACE= pygame.display.set_mode([S_WIDTH,S_HEIGHT])
    MAIN_CLOCK= pygame.time.Clock()
    CURSOR= cursor()
    FLASHLIGHT= flashlight()
    SHADOW= shadow()
    BG_IMG= pygame.image.load("B:/Proyectos pygame/Luz/BG_IMAGE.jpg")

    while True:
        MAIN_CLOCK.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        S_SURFACE.blit(BG_IMG,[0,0])
        SHADOW.render(S_SURFACE)
        CURSOR.update()
        FLASHLIGHT.move(CURSOR)
        FLASHLIGHT.render(S_SURFACE)        
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But the problem is that it only draw a rectangle! In the class shadow when it creates the rectangles it determine its position by adding the size of the rectangles to the position of the following rectangle and later it save the rectangles in a list.

Comment: Maybe some screen shots will help - I for one, have no idea what your code is actually doing, or what you expect.

Comment: Here is a screenshoot: http://fotos.subefotos.com/dd48044daa9426a8e0848ec362390251o.png

Comment: What I expect is that it draw this image more times until it covers all the screen

Comment: look at your call to surface.blit - I can't help thinking you are passing the wrong details to the call, and you are drawing all of your rectangles to the same place - although I don't have the time to debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is due to what happens in the`shadow.render()`method:

```
def render(self,surface,rect):
    for shadow in self.list:
        surface.blit(shadow["img"], shadow["rect"])
```

Because the`shadow["rect"]`argument passed in the`surface.blit()`call as the`dest`argument is the same value for each dictionary object that was appended to in the`self.list`.

Note: I suggest you start following the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) coding guidelines which specifies that class names, like`cursor`,`flashlight`, and`shadow`, be capitalized because it makes reading and debugging your own as well as other people's code easier if everyone follows the same conventions.

The naming styles for different types of program artifacts often supplies useful additional information implicitly to readers of the code. As a concrete example, one would know that`Shadow`was the name of the class instance that`self`refers to and that`shadow`was just the name of some local variable (that probably refers to some other instance of the same class).